# Suggestion on logging with static class

Tags: c#

I am currently facing an issue related to logging messages in my WPF application.

I am keeping a static class for logging messages throughout my application which contains a function

```
private SomeService service = new SomeService();

private void LogMessage(string message)
{
   service.Log(message);
}
```

My issue is in my screens where I require logging, I append strings from different places in the screen and pass it to the LogMessage function. I have very large data to be logged from different places within the screen.

Now the issue I am facing is that a new member has been introduced ie

```
public bool IsLoggingEnabled = false;
```

Now I need to check this condition each time before appending the string like this

```
if(ClassName.IsLoggingEnabled)
{
    var msg = string.Format("Log 1 : {0}, Log 2 : {1}, Log 3 : {2} .... ", 0,1,2);
}

if(ClassName.IsLoggingEnabled)
{
    msg += string.Format("Log 4 : {0}, Log 5 : {1}, Log 6 : {2} .... ", 4,5,6);
}

...............

ClassName.LogMessage(msg);
```

Could you please suggest  a solution for handling this scenario?
Is it good to append all the messages and finally check the condition. Or check the condition within the LogMessage function?

But I felt these as wrong ways. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: If `IsLoggingEnabled` is defined in the same class as `LogMessage` then just put the `if` in the `LogMessage` method and keep all of the calling classes clean - they would just call `LogMessage`.

Comment: You're re-inventing the wheel. Logging frameworks can dispatch log messages. E.g., you can use severity level and logger configuration to decide whether to write in log or not. `IsLoggingEnabled` smells. Moreover, static logger isn't good solution too - when you will decide to move from one logger to another (and this is just a matter of time usually), it will be hard to do this.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Thanks for the suggestion. But that will be unnecessarily calling the function even when logging is not required. Anyways that's one of the possible ways.

Comment: @Dennis: I am already using some logging service. The question is about when to decide to call the LogMessage function and when to create the string argument.

Comment: @IDisposable: call `LogMesage` unconditionally. Let logging framework to decide, when it must perform actual logging.

Comment: @IDisposable - Now you have two people suggesting you just call the log function and let it decide.

Comment: @Enigmativity: Yes I agree with that method that you and Dennis suggested. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can instead check this parameter in your login class and keep it transparent to the other places you use it:

```
private void LogMessage(string message) 
{ 
    if(ClassName.IsLoggingEnabled)
    {
        service.Log(message); 
    }
}
```

About the string concatenation why not to just write it in separate logs - each log in it's own call. Makes code clearer and with less state.

Last, I think a better implementation is to have your class dependent on an `ILogger` instance and to just use it. Somewhere it'll be initialized and passed to your class. This will make it easier for you for change the logging class and to test your other classes.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I will check it.

Answer (score 1):

With your current implementation, the `IsLoggingEnabled` property can be moved to the static `LogMessage` and the property can be set once when the project is loaded or through code or from external config file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.